# ActionBarDrawerToggle is visible but onClick is not working

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to add my own icon to the ActionBarDrawerToggle (android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle). The custom icon is visible but it is not responding to clicks. I can see my side menu when i slide my finger from left to right but click is not working.
I have tried this solution but it is working and i don't want to use toolbar. I want solution to add this icon without toolbar, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482825/changing-navigation-drawer-icon-on-action-bar-android).

This is my code. Sorry for too many lines.

```
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.layout_for_title);
        CustomTextViewToolbar head=(CustomTextViewToolbar)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("mytext", "id", getPackageName()));
        head.setText("Home");
        ImageView gender = (ImageView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("gender" , "id" , getPackageName()));
        gender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_gender);


                dialog.show();
                CircularImageView male = (CircularImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.male) ;
                male.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                CircularImageView female = (CircularImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.female) ;
                female.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                CircularImageView kids = (CircularImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.kids) ;
                kids.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("show_cart" , "id" , getPackageName()));
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext() ,  CustomerCartActivity.class));
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.customer_home_screen);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();
        mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);

        initItems();

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header, null, false);
        mExpandableListView.addHeaderView(listHeaderView);

        mExpandableListData = ExpandableListDataSource.getData(this);
        mExpandableListTitle = new ArrayList(mExpandableListData.keySet());

        addDrawerItems();
       setupDrawer();



        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectFirstItemAsDefault();
        }
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
        coverFlow = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);

        mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        horizontal_recycler_view= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler_view);
        data = fill_with_data();
        horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalAdapter(data, getApplication());
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);


        coverFlowOne = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow_one);
        coverFlowTwo = (FeatureCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflowtwo);
        settingDummyData();
        adapter = new CoverFlowAdapter(this, games);
        coverFlow.setAdapter(adapter);
        coverFlow.setOnScrollPositionListener(onScrollListener());
        coverFlowOne.setAdapter(adapter);
        coverFlowOne.setOnScrollPositionListener(onScrollListener());
        coverFlowTwo.setAdapter(adapter);
        coverFlowTwo.setOnScrollPositionListener(onScrollListener());
        myHome = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.c_home);
        myOrder  = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.c_my_order);
        myAccount = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.c_profile);


        myHome.setOnClickListener(this);
        myOrder.setOnClickListener(this);
        myAccount.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private void selectFirstItemAsDefault() {
        if (mNavigationManager != null) {
            String firstActionMovie = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionFilms)[0];
            mNavigationManager.showFragmentAction(firstActionMovie);
        }
    }

    private void initItems() {
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.film_genre);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        mExpandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, mExpandableListTitle, mExpandableListData);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(mExpandableListAdapter);


        mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((List) (mExpandableListData.get(mExpandableListTitle.get(groupPosition))))
                        .get(childPosition).toString();


                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.menu_icon);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried dropping this line `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`

Comment: yes i tried dropping `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);`
but nothing happens then also 
then i tried `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);`
but this gives the default toggle ham icon and 
with `mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` i can see my custom icon but it does not receive any click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set you new icon to "clickable" in the xml?
Enable the Debug GPU Overdraw tool.  It *may* give you an indication whether or not your icon is overlapped by another element that is consuming clicks (if so you will need to make that overlapping element clickable to false).

> On your mobile device, go to Settings and tap Developer Options.
>
> In the Hardware accelerated rendering section, select Debug GPU Overdraw.
>
> In the Debug GPU overdraw popup, select Show overdraw areas.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/dev-options-overdraw.html

Alternatively add debugging onClick functions to potentially overlapping or conflicting elements.

Comment: `@Sam Boychuk`  your suggestion was really helpful to me, i did same as you asked me to do,but i can clearly see that my custom icon is not overlapped by any other element and it is showing touch when i click on it, the point is
its not closing and opening the side menu

Comment: `@Sam Boychuk` marked your answer as accepted as it helped me in searching a better solution
i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745001/navigation-drawer-actionbar-button-not-working) useful