# ActionBarDrawerToggle isn't working till the time i manually swipe right to open the navigation drawer. After this, it responds perfectly

Tags: android

**Problem:**
When I open my application and click on the ActionBarDrawerToggle, it doesn't open the navigation drawer. However, when i swipe right and then open and close the navigation drawer, after this the ActionBarDrawerToggle repsonds perfectly fine, like it should, by opening the drawer.

**My HomeScreen.java**

```
    public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private NavigationView navigationView;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

            instantiateViews();
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
    }

        public void instantiateViews(){

                toolbar = findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu_toolbar);
                drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.home_screen_main_drawer_layout);
                navigationView = findViewById(R.id.home_screen_navigation_view);

            }

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_share:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_logout:
                    session.logoutUser();
                    break;

            }
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }

}
```

I have tried everything from the following thread: [Navigation Drawer ActionBar button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745001/navigation-drawer-actionbar-button-not-working) even though for that person the ActionBarDrawerToggle wasn't working under all circumstances but mine isn't working till the time navigation drawer is opened. After that mine works perfectly

**What I have tried doing:**

1.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

2.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle.syncState();
```

3.

```
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

None of these work for me

**My home_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Top Layout-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchHere"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"
                    android:hint="Search Here"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/home_screen_menu_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/home_screen_menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
}
```

Comment: Are you using two toolbar

Comment: yes, one has the ActionBarDrawerToggle, placed on top, second has a search text view, placed 10 dp from the bottom of the layout it is present in i.e 110dp from top of the screen

Comment: I am finally being able to register the clicks when the ActionBarToggle is clicked in the 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("CLICKED","clicked");
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }. In the log i am able to get CLICKED: clicked but using the above command to open the drawer is still not working. can anyone help me with what should i write instead of drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

Comment: Do you have user ' getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); ' after toggle.syncState();

Comment: I added that, now instead of the 3 menu lines, it is showing a back arrow, but the same problem persisits. Now the back arrow actually works like the menu icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, or Try to take out your Toolbar from Relative Layout.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I have done some minor modification in your layout i hope it will help you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_main_drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Top Layout-->

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:background="@color/blue">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen">


                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/searchHere"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"
                        android:hint="Search Here"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/home_screen_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/home_screen_menu_drawer_header"
            app:menu="@menu/home_screen_menu_drawer"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```