# First click on toggle button not work, but after drawable opened yes

Tags: android, toggle, drawable, android-drawable

I need help.
When I want to open the DrawableLayout, I press the toggle button there for the first time it doesn't respond.
After I opened the DrawableLayout by swipe and close it, then toggle starts working properly.
Here is a [Youtube link](https://youtu.be/a_EvghlqxJc) to the problem and some code segment.

Segment of kotlin class

```
//region Drawable layout
    private fun initDrawableLayout() {
        setUpNavigationView()
        setToolbar()
        setToggleActionBar()
    }

    private fun setUpNavigationView() {
        binding.mainNavView.bringToFront()
        binding.mainNavView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    private fun setToggleActionBar() {
        var toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            binding.mainDrawerLayout,
            binding.mainToolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close
        )
        binding.mainDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
    }

    private fun setToolbar() {
        binding.toolbarTitleTv.text = getString(R.string.home)
    }
```

Segment of xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/main_color"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.DayNight.ActionBar">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_tv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:text="Home" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/top_navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_icons_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawable_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your app_bar_main layout. Meanwhile, you can look at these threads for some similar problems. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56682697/actionbardrawertoggle-isnt-working-till-the-time-i-manually-swipe-right-to-open   And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824324/clicking-hamburger-icon-on-toolbar-does-not-open-navigation-drawer

Comment: @Akki did it. Tell me you need some other information

Comment: Have you added the click listener onOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: @Akki yes i did it and after i open menu by swipe from left to right button start work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I needed to delete visibility = gone from NavigationView in xml file.
Maybe it will help to somebody.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawable_menu" />
```